# Ansible print hostnames / variables in list / table

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Is there a way with Ansible to print out a simple table style output.  I've got the values I need registered to a variable in the playbook I just want to print it out more cleanly.
Currently the output I have with stdout.lines looks like this:

```
ok: [sage] => {
    "voutput.stdout_lines": [
        "4.4.5"
    ]
}

ok: [example] => {
    "voutput.stdout_lines": [
        "4.7"
    ]
}
```

But it'd be nice if I could get it formatted more like this:

```
sage              4.7
example           4.4.5
somethingelse     1.2.3
```

Is there any way to do something along those lines directly within Ansible, or do I just have to take the output it gives and transform it with something like AWK?

Answer (score 4):

You can use standard json output callback and fetch required data with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

hosts:

```
[test]
srv1 testvar=abc
srv2 testvar=zzzzzz
srv3 testvar=qqqq
```

playbook.yml:

```
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: var=testvar
```

execution:

```
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible-playbook playbook.yml | jq -r '.plays[0].tasks[0].hosts | to_entries[] | "\(.key), \(.value.testvar)"'
srv1, abc
srv2, zzzzzz
srv3, qqqq
```

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like a good start, but when I use the ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json, then the variable registered during playbook execution isn't in the list of the output.  Taking that off gets me back to where I have the typical Ansible output, but the variable does print its value.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- alter the log output of Ansible using [Callback Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins). It will require some Python coding. Unfortunately move of the [example plugins](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback) seem to fulfill your requirements.
- use a Jinja2 template and save the output to a file with either a [`template`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) or a [`copy`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) module with `content` parameter.

  First you'd need to combine the dictionaries into a list and iterate over items in the template.